# How do I convert a string into a non string?

Tags: python, string

how to convert a string to a non string in python?

```
>>> bits=['0100','0011','1110','1001','0100']
>>> a=map(int,bits)
>>> print a
```

we have this as output

```
[100, 11, 1110, 1001, 100]
```

but we want this

```
[0100,0011,1110,1001,0100]
```

is this possible whithout using for loops?

Comment: You have integers, you'll have to re-format them as strings with padding.

Comment: What do you need this for? Integer with leading zeros is no different than without them.

Comment: Do you mean octal numbers by leading 0?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to format each integer before printing:

```
print '[' + ', '.join(map(lambda i: format(i, '04d'), a)) + ']'
```

or use:

```
print '[' + ', '.join(bits) + ']'
```

*without* first converting all the strings to integers.

Demo:

```
>>> bits=['0100','0011','1110','1001','0100']
>>> a=map(int,bits)
>>> print '[' + ', '.join(map(lambda i: format(i, '04d'), a)) + ']'
[0100, 0011, 1110, 1001, 0100]
>>> print '[' + ', '.join(bits) + ']'
[0100, 0011, 1110, 1001, 0100]
```

Note that if your `bits` strings are meant to be binary values, you'd need to interpret them as such:

```
>>> int('0100', 2)
4
>>> format(4, '04b')
'0100'
```

This converts a string of zeros and ones into an integer by interpreting the digits as binary, and converts an integer number back into a binary string representation using 4 digits and 0-padding.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Python's default implementation to print a list, you can roll your own:

```
>>> bits=['0100','0011','1110','1001','0100']
>>> print '[' + ','.join(bits) + ']'
[0100,0011,1110,1001,0100]
```

In this case, because the items inside the `bits` list are already padded and are strings, there's no reason to convert to ints or any other datatype at any point.

If you literally want a list of numbers that are padded, then your original code is sufficient. It may not display the 0s to the left, but since they're numbers, you don't need them.